# Where to find 1911 sub-districts in order?

Tags: england, census-records, death-records, 1910s, civil-registration

I am trying to work out which of two death records in Wakefield registration district is my ancestor.

To do this I need the subdistricts listed in the order they come on the census.

I don’t know where to look for this in 1911.

Comment: Hi, Joanna, Welcome to G&FH.SE!

Answer (score 7):

The report you want is available on [Histpop.org](http://www.histpop.org).

Specifically, go to page 286 of the report titled: [*Areas, families or separate occupiers, and population, England and Wales, Vol. II. Registration areas, 1911*](http://www.histpop.org/ohpr/servlet/PageBrowser?path=Browse/Census%20(by%20date)/1911&active=yes&mno=140&tocstate=expandnew&display=sections&display=tables&display=pagetitles&pageseq=296&zoom=4).

This shows the sub-districts (in the order they were enumerated) in Wakefield Registration District at the time of the 1911 census:

1. Bretton
2. Sandal
3. Horbury
4. Wakefield
5. Ardsley
6. Stanley
7. Normanton

An excerpt of that page (which also helpfully includes the constituent parishes of each sub-district:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harry this is exactly what I was looking for.